# Can we add carriage return ('\n') to the resx file in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, resx, carriage-return

I have hard coded the carriage return in my codebehind so as to adjust the new lines in english. Now that i have localised my app, it turns out tht the '\n' is at unnecessary places,
Is there any way to add the '\n' to the resx file so that i can use when and where i need it? 
I have tried assigning \n to a string , but it displays '\n' on the screen :( Any other way to do it?

Alfah

Comment: You may be better off adding support for wrapping in the UI, rather than trying to manually adjust the position of new lines in your resources. If you'r manually adding them at different places for differnt languages/translations, it suggests that you're not always having them at the end of sentences.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, I know you can ... I have done it.  Try `Shift+Enter` ... and if that doesn't work, copy and paste it in from Notepad.

Comment: Shift+Enter works in both the resx and the xlf editor (VS2012).